# Is there a way to store the version information in a Rust compiled executable or library?

Tags: dll, rust, versioning, rust-cargo

When a Rust binary (executable or dylib) is built, the version information configured in `Cargo.toml` has no effect on the binary built, meaning the configured version is not stored inside the binary file.

In Linux, when I use `readelf -V` for a .so file, you can see the supported interface (SO Name) is stored under the **Version definition section '.gnu.version_d'** of the ELF file. For example, the output of `readelf -V /lib/libnss_files-2.12.so`:

```
Version definition section '.gnu.version_d' contains 2 entries:
   Addr: 0x0000000000001540  Offset: 0x001540  Link: 5 (.dynstr)
   000000: Rev: 1  Flags: BASE   Index: 1  Cnt: 1  Name: libnss_files.so.2
   0x001c: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 2  Cnt: 1  Name: GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

The `/lib/libnss_files-2.12.so` file is implementing interface version `libnss_files.so.2`

The `readelf -V` output for a Rust or Cargo generated dylib or executable has no such version information. The version config in `Cargo.toml` is only used by crates.io.

**Moreover**, Windows DLLs support storing the version information, not the SONAME interface version name like Linux. A cross-compiled Windows DLL also has no version info. Perhaps this is another question, but I thought I'd raise the point here first.

Comment: It was [cross posted to reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3zi8xh/no_rust_version_info_stored_in_dylib_dynamic_link/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While I don't think there is an immediate way to use ELF facilities for versioning (they are not cross-platform anyway), it is possible to use version information from Cargo:

```
const VERSION: &'static str = env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION");
```

`VERSION` will now be equal to the version specified in the manifest when `cargo build` is run. Alternatively, you can use `env_opt!()` if you want to build your program without Cargo:

```
const VERSION: Option<&'static str> = env_opt!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION");
```

Comment: Then how can i read the version info after I get the final built binary?

Comment: Well, `VERSION` is just a regular constant, so make your program print it when you run it in a certain way, for example, by passing `-v` command line argument (like lots of CLI tools do): `your-program -v`. Again, as I said, this is not related to version information specific to the binary format (ELF headers, PE headers or anything else).

Comment: Ok, that means I cannot view the version without run the code in the lib. But it's ok to know about this fact. Do you know is there any plan Cargo/Rust use the OS's native facilities for versioning?

Comment: @palazzotrain, no, I haven't heard of any such plans. But you can always submit a feature request to [Cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues) and [Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues) issue trackers. I think such change wouldn't require an RFC, though I may be wrong, of course.

Comment: I post a request to Cargo issue tracker. https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2273.

Answer (score 4):

To give an update on the accepted answer. In Rust 2021 the 2nd macro mentioned in the answer (`env_opt`) is now accessible via [`std::option_env`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.option_env.html)

```rust
const CARGO_PKG_VERSION: Option<&'static str> = option_env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION");
```

And afterwards, you may use it as like

```rust
info!("Booting up... VERSION={}", CARGO_PKG_VERSION.unwrap_or("NOT_FOUND"));
```

Furthermore, as a note, if you want to include, for example, a default config in the binary, the macro [`std::include_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

use winres(https://github.com/mxre/winres) can set CARGO_PKG_VERSION to dll file version, maybe help for others